# Itamaeのexecuteリソースを使う際に環境変数を指定する方法

Tags: go, itamae

`go`で書かれた`cron`の代替になる`jobber`を Ubuntu に`Itamae`を使ってインストールするために

```
execute 'export GOPATH=$HOME/.go; go get github.com/dshearer/jobber' do
  not_if 'test -e ~/.go/src/github.com/dshearer/jobber'
end

execute 'export GOPATH=$HOME/.go; cd ~/.go/src/github.com/dshearer/jobber; git checkout v1.0.3; make' do
  not_if 'test -e ~/.go/bin/jobber'
end
```

のような書き方をして実際に動いてはいるんですが、
せめて環境変数の指定ぐらいはもう少し上手くやりたいと考えています。

`ENV['GOPATH'] = '$HOME/.go'`を指定しても`$GOPATH`が未定義だとエラーになってしまいます。

`Chef`なら`execute`リソースに`environment`属性を指定すれば環境変数を指定できたようなのですが`Itamae`には実装されていないようです。

https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/wiki/execute-resource

別の場所で指定することはできますか？

Answer (score 1):

goでGOPATHの指定は環境変数を設定するしか無いですね。
Itamaeの挙動を利用するとか、envコマンド併用するとか。